# How can I intercept commands that contain a certain string?

Tags: bash

Sometimes, it happens to me that I'm executing certain commands, and only afterwards I realize that I sent the wrong parameter to a command ( like a restart of a Heroku application ). I'd like to modify bash in such a way that if it sees a command containing a certain string, it will prompt me whether I'm sure or not. For example ( imagine the string is tempus ):

```
$ heroku restart --app tempus
```

Now, I'd like bash to prompt me with a Y/N prompt, and if I type `y`, only then I'd like it to execute the command. If I type N, the command will not be executed. How could I handle this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any way to intercept all bash commands, but you can intercept predetermined commands using the following trick.

1. Create a directory (say `~/interception`) and set it as the first entry in `$PATH`
2. Create the following script in that directory with a list of commands you wish to intercept and the full path to the actual command

   ```
   [bash]$ cat intercept.sh
   #!/bin/bash

   # map commands to full path
   declare -A COMMANDS
   COMMANDS[heroku]=/usr/bin/heroku
   COMMANDS[grep]=/bin/grep
   # ... more ...

   CMD=$(basename $0)  # command used to call this script

   if [[ ! -z "${COMMANDS[$CMD]+x}" ]]; then  # mapping found
     # Do what you wish here. You can even modify/inspect the params.
     echo "intercepted $CMD command... "

     ${COMMANDS[$CMD]} $@   # run actual command with all params
   else
     echo "Unknown command $CMD"
   fi
   ```
3. In the same directory, create symlinks to that script using the name of the commands you wish to intercept

   ```
   [bash]$ ln -s intercept.sh grep
   [bash]$ ln -s intercept.sh heroku
   ```

Now, each time you call the command, that script is invoked via the symlink and it can then do your bidding before calling the actual command.

You can extend this further by sourcing the `$COMMANDS` from a config file and create helper commands to augment the config file and create/remove the sym links. You would then be able to manage the who setup using commands such as:

```
intercept_add `which heroku`
intercept_remove heroku
intercept_list
```

Answer (score 2):

Because bash itself doesn't support command line filter, it's not possible to intercept commands.

Here is a dirty solution:

1. Find all executables in PATH and create wrapper functions for each of them.
2. The wrapper function then call `prefilter()` function if it's declared.
3. If `prefilter()` function failed, the command is canceled.

SOURCE: cmd-wrap.sh

```
#!/bin/bash  # The shebang is only useful for debug. Don't execute this script.

function create_wrapper() {
    local exe="$1"
    local name="${exe##*/}"

    # Only create wrappers for non-builtin commands
    [ `type -t "$name"` = 'file' ] || return

    # echo "Create command wrapper for $exe"
    eval "
    function $name() {\
        if [ \"\$(type -t prefilter)\" = 'function' ]; then \
            prefilter \"$name\" \"\$@\" || return; \
        fi; \
        $exe \"\$@\";
    }"
}
# It's also possible to add pre/post hookers by install
#   [ `type -t \"$name-pre\"` = 'function' ] && \"$name-pre\" \"\$@\"
# into the dynamic generated function body.

function _create_wrappers() {
    local paths="$PATH"
    local path
    local f n

    while [ -n "$paths" ]; do
        path="${paths%%:*}"
        if [ "$path" = "$paths" ]; then
            paths=
        else
            paths="${paths#*:}"
        fi

        # For each path element:
        for f in "$path"/*; do
            if [ -x "$f" ]; then
                # Don't create wrapper for strange command names.
                n="${f##*/}"
                [ -n "${n//[a-zA-Z_-]/}" ] || create_wrapper "$f"
            fi
        done
    done

    unset _create_wrappers  # Remove the installer.
    unset create_wrapper    # Remove the helper fn, which isn't used anymore.
}

_create_wrappers
```

To utilize it for your problem:

1. source it in bash:

   ```
   . ./cmd-wrap.sh
   ```
2. Create your version of `prefilter()` to check if any argument contains the string:

   ```
   function prefilter() {
       local a y
       for a in "$@"; do
           if [ "$a" != "${a/tempus}" ]; then
               echo -n "WARNING: The command contains tempus. Continue?"
               read y
               [ "$y" = 'Y' ] || [ "$y" = 'y' ]
               return $?
           fi
       done
       return 0
   }
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   heroku restart --app tempus
   ```

   but not

   ```
   /usr/bin/heroku restart --app tempus
   ```

   to make use of the wrapper function.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use aliases.  This simple example should work for you:

This protects from executing the heroku command with tempus in the arguments

```
function protect_heroku {
    # use grep to determine if the bad string is in arguments
    echo "$*" | grep tempus > /dev/null
    # if string is not in arguments
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        # run the protected command using its full path, so as not to trigger alias
        /path/to/heroku "$@"
    else
        # get user confirmation
        echo -n Are you sure \(y/n\)?' '
        read CONFIRM
        if [ "$CONFIRM" = y ]; then
            # run the protected command using its full path
            /path/to/heroku "$@"
        fi
    fi
}

# This is the key:
# This alias command means that 'heroku' from now refers
# to the function protect_heroku, rather than /bin/heroku
alias heroku=protect_heroku
```

Put this code into your bash profile ~/.profile and then log out and log back in.  From now on, bash will protect you from accidentally running heroku with tempus.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to replace `heroku` with a script that does the checking before executing the real heroku. Another way would be to add a bash alias for `heroku`.